# How can I plot x**2 + y**2 = 9 as a circle not 3d equation in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, sympy

How can I plot x^2 + y^2 = 9 as a circle not 3d equation in python

I cannot find any where to plot equality equation in python. Can you please help me out in this.

Comment: There seem to be multible functions to plot circles with for example matplotlib. As I do not know the context of your questions here the link to different methods: https://www.pythonpool.com/matplotlib-circle/

Answer (score 2):

You can use sympy as follows:

```
from sympy import Eq, plot_implicit
from sympy.abc import x, y

plot_implicit(Eq(x ** 2 + y ** 2, 9), aspect_ratio=(1, 1))
```

[image: sympy plot_implicit]

There is also `plot_parametric`:

```py
from sympy import plot_parametric, cos, sin, pi
from sympy.abc import t

plot_parametric(cos(t), sin(t), (t, 0, 2 * pi), aspect_ratio=(1, 1))
```

Comment: is there anything similar for 3d plot

Comment: There are `plot3d_parametric_line()`  and `plot3d_parametric_surface()`, see the [sympy plotting docs](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/plotting.html) for usage and examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can derive x,y by solving the equation.
For example, noting that `-3 <= x <= 3` and `y = +- sqrt(9-x^2)`,

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-3, 3)
y = np.sqrt(9-x)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.scatter(x, -y)
```

[image]

Alternatively, since this relation can be expressed by the polar coordinate `0 <= theta < 2*pi` with `x = 3 cos(theta), y = 3 sin(theta),`

```py
theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi)
x = 3*np.cos(theta)
y = 3*np.sin(theta)

plt.scatter(x, y)
```

[image]